# Give up permissions using facebook javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook, permissions

I'm working on an integration with the Facebook Timeline and want to have a separate opt-in feature just for it for users. If a user opts in now, I get the `publish_actions` permission so I can post things to the timeline. If they later opt-out is there any way for me to tell Facebook I no longer want that permission for that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revoke permissions for your app by performing a DELETE on `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/permissions?permission=xxxx`.

> You can de-authorize an application or revoke a specific extended permissions on behalf of a user by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to PROFILE_ID/permissions with a user access_token for that app.  [Facebook User API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

---

*Parameter*:

> **permission** - The permission you wish to revoke. If you don't specify a permission then this will de-authorize the application completely.